# Qt Installer InstallerApplicationIcon does not appear on Installer

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I have created a qt installer and I am trying to set some icons on it,
Working on linux with the InstallerApplicationIcon I have managed the application logo to be displayed on each of Installer's page but building the same installer on Windows the Icon does not appear. I have tried several solutions with .ico or .bmp files but I have not managed to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I found that in Windows 'InstallerApplicationIcon' without filename extension, but 'InstallerWindowIcon' needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on windows and it worked for me.

Inside my config directory I have two files `Coffee.ico` and `document.png`. The `Coffee.ico` is shown in the explorer for the installer icon, whereas the `document.png` is shown on every installer page on the top.

My `config.xml` basically looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>Your application</Name> 
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Title>Your application Installer</Title>
    <InstallerApplicationIcon>Coffee</InstallerApplicationIcon>
    <InstallerWindowIcon>Document.png</InstallerWindowIcon>
</Installer>
```

Here is what I'll see:

[image: Icon in Explorer]

[image: Icon inside installer pages]

Comment: I am not referring to the icon position you are mentioning I am referring to the Application Logo to Up-Right section of the installer

Comment: @chatzich: Can you please extend your question with an screenshot of your Linux and Windows installer?

Comment: I wish I could but I am working in private network and I can not export code from it